# Problem with Rgdal package on R software version 3.5.1

Tags: r, package, load, rgdal

I'm trying to load in R a shapefile but I can't do it.
When I load a Rgdal package I have this error message

> "rgdal: version: 1.3-6, (SVN revision 773)
>    Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
>    Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
>    Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/Matteo/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rgdal/gdal
>    GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
>    Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
>    Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/Matteo/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rgdal/proj
>    Linking to sp version: 1.3-1 "

What may have happened?

I tried to update the package but the problem remains.

My version of R is 3.5.1 and my PC is Windows

Comment: This is not an error. This is information about the GDAL library version as well as other library versions. There's a reason it does this (different GDAL & other library versions have different features and bugs). You can safely continue your analysis. If you wish to suppress these messages you can use `suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rgdal))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like an error message to me, just some loading notes.

You can confirm that the package is loaded, if you're using RStudio, under the "Packages" pane in the lower right-hand corner; the rgdal package should have a check mark next to it.

Alternatively, you can use `print(.packages())`, which will give you a list of all your loaded packages.